# Getting "Multiple markers at this line" when reading from a file in Omnet++

Tags: omnet++

```
std::ifstream in (par("pathFile"));
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - candidates are:
    - call of overloaded 'basic_ifstream(cPar&)' is ambiguous
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
std::ifstream in (par("pathFile").stringValue());
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17804185)

Comment: I am able to reproduce the error presented by @Mohammed Sani and I don't need a clarification. In `OMNeT++` the `par()` method returns a reference to `cPar` object which - in the presented code - is not automatically cast to `char *` [reference](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/api/classomnetpp_1_1cComponent.html#af5506335b59111e62cf6292f411f9a9f) . Therefore it requires manual cast to `char *` using `stringValue()`.